# Permanently disable time machine prompting for external disks

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine

Is it possible to disable time machine prompting when inserting external disks?

I use an appliance with SATA disks that regularly formats the disks.  Whenever I plug such a disk in I get prompted again for time-machine - since the time-machine opt-out file is deleted.

This can happen 10s of times per hour and is rather frustrating.

I'd be happy for total disable of prompting, but better would probably to make it per interface (ie USB - i use a USB->SATA device) or per device (ie just the SATA dock I'm using)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Turn Off Requests To Use New Disks for Time Machine [OS X Tips]](http://www.cultofmac.com/141070/turn-off-requests-to-use-new-disks-for-time-machine-os-x-tips/)...

You can stop this request dialog box from appearing by opening a Terminal window (Finder -> Applications -> Utilities – > Terminal) and typing the following:

```
defaults write com.apple.TimeMachine DoNotOfferNewDisksForBackup -bool TRUE
```

Then log out and back in again for the changes to take effect.

If you’d like to restore the request dialog at a later date, again open Terminal then type the following (log out and back in again after for the changes to take effect):

```
defaults delete com.apple.TimeMachine DoNotOfferNewDisksForBackup
```

Comment: Thanks - that works - I'll wait before accepting to encourage any more specific answers if they exist.